# DNS client(dnscache) keeps crashing cause system to crash on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns, crash

My browsers don't response sometimes, when it occurs, I can't open a new page, and browsers keep no response. Gradually I can't open new apps which require networking, even the system apps and settings such as "networking and Internet settings" and I can not disconnect the network in the taskbar. Then my system begins to freeze and crash, I can't finish some processes in task manager gradually and the system reacts so slowly that it freezes(But I can still open some apps and games that don't require networking). Restarting the computer can solve the problems, but it keeps occurs almost every day. It's really annoying.

I found some useful message in Reliability Monitor. It seems every time something goes wrong the system can catch a dnscache crash. The "svchost.exe_Dnscache" goes wrong, the error model is "dnsrslvr.dll".
Then I found when the issues starts to occurs, I can quickly disconnect the networking and finish the DNS Client process to solve the problem. when I do this, the DNS Client process and the dnscache service restarts and everything goes well, the browsers back to normal and all the apps that couldn't be opened just now can be opened in a second(It seems like when the door opens and people rush in).

I still can not solve the problems and the cause of the issues could not be found. The security and antivirus software can't find any problems either(When the problems occurs even the security software  keeps no response, so I uninstall it). I tried to flush the dns by cmd, I tried the Dism tools and sfc to scan and restore my system files. But all of these didn't seem to work.

Comment: When did this issue start to occur? Before the issue happened, did you do any modifications? Or install any updates? What's the OS version of the windows 10? 1909 or 2004? Was windows 10 machine domain-joined? Please clarify more details about your environment.

Comment: The issue occured about 2 month ago, I came to a new school at that time and my laptop started to access to the campus networking, before that I only use the computer at home, and every thing was fine. My roomates didn't have this problem.The OS version is 1909. The computer comes pre-loaded with Lenovo's security software which has now been uninstalled. The machine didn't joined any domain. I deployed a vps server for my computer, but before that the issue had occured.